# Microsoft Azure DocumentDb Maximum Storage Capacity

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

So I am hitting the 10 GB maximum storage capacity for Azure DocumentDb every few  months.

I noticed recently Microsoft has added a partitioned mode that raises the maximum storage capacity to 250 GB but the problem is that the minimum throughput (RU/s) is 10,100 which jumps the price to ~$606 a month from around $25 a month.

Is there anyway to increase storage capacity while keeping the throughput around throughput around 400?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using partitioned collections, you'd need to create multiple non-partitioned collections, as needed. The SDKs have partitioning support (or you can shard data across partitions as you see fit).

**EDIT**: Please note that the minimum RU for partitioned collections is no longer 10,100 RU (as mentioned in the original question). It's now 400 RU (as of late 2018).

Comment: Note that if you do decide to do partitioning over single collections or old S1-S3 you will need to handle re-sharding yourself, including dealing with reads and writes during re-sharding.

Comment: Ah, makes sense to have storage restrictions on partitions so things don't get out of control and to scale out with multiple partitions. Thanks for the info!